# Type.IsByRef always returning false

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I think I don't understand what `Type.IsByRef` property from .NET is supposed to indicate. I thought it's supposed to return true for reference types and false for value types, so the opposite of `Type.IsValueType` property. I can't get it to return true for types that are obviously reference types though. Here's an example:

```
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(i.GetType().IsByRef);    // returns false - OK

            Exception e = new Exception();
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().IsByRef);    // returns false - ??

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine(sb.GetType().IsByRef);   // returns false - ??
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IsByRef` is true for parameters passed by reference:

```
public void Foo(ref int x) { }
...

var fooMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Foo");
var param = fooMethod.GetParameters()[0];
bool isByRef = param.ParameterType.IsByRef; // true
```

It's unrelated to value types and reference types. To check if a type is a value type, check `IsValueType` (which returns true for a value type, false otherwise).

Comment: Thanks! It really does work like you explained. I guess the example in the MSDN article is misleading then. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isbyref%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @S_F well, that is tricky... not quite; it is right, but not very clearly phrased; there's a difference between the *type being a reference type*, and the *type itself being a reference*. The MSDN article is talking about the latter - you are talking about the former. Note that you can have both at once: a reference to a reference-type (`ref string`, for example)